# Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, syntax

I've been instructed "not to bother with `LIKE`" and use `~` instead. What is wrong with `LIKE` and how is `~` different?

Does `~` have a name in this context or do people say "use the tilde operator"?

Comment: Instructed by whom, out of interest? I'm curious.

Comment: @CraigRinger Course instructor.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I just meant "where" more than "whom", sorry.

Comment: Foolish advice. ~ is a regex operator, LIKE isn't . ~ is more powerful but LIKE is (significantly) more performant.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`~` is the regular expression operator, and has the capabilities implied by that.  You can specify a full range of regular expression wildcards and quantifiers; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for details.  It is certainly more powerful than `LIKE`, and should be used when that power is needed, but they serve different purposes.

Comment: This is very bad advice. Whenever you can use the SQL standard `LIKE` it is generally preferable to a regular expression. It is simpler, much faster and easier to use with appropriate indexes. Regular expressions are more powerful, but slower and non-standard.

Comment: That's why I said "when appropriate, but they serve different purposes."

Comment: `should be used in preference to the LIKE operator when appropriate` is just wrong. When you have a choice, use LIKE. When you don't have a choice, you don't have a choice anyway.

Comment: Have you not seen people trying to shoehorn pattern matching into a query with multiple LIKE clauses?  That's necessary in some other systems, but Postgres offers the regex operator.  Perhaps I should say:  "should be used in preference to multiple LIKE clauses."

Comment: Edited to reflect this discussion.

Comment: Removed the downvote accordingly as the answer doesn't strike me as wrong any more.

Comment: It should be noted that LIKE is should be preferred because "LIKE searches, being much simpler than the other two options, are safer to use with possibly-hostile pattern sources." - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 56):

#### Overview

`LIKE`, `SIMILAR TO` and `~` are the basic [pattern matching operators in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

If you can, use **`LIKE`** (**`~~`**), it's fastest and simplest.
If you can't, use a regular expression (**`~`**), it's more powerful.
Never user <strike>**`SIMILAR TO`**</strike>. It's pointless. See below.

Installing the [additional module pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) adds advanced index options and the [similarity operator **`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE).
And there is also [text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) with its own infrastructure and the [**`@@`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-OPERATORS-TABLE) (among others).

Index support is available for each of these operators - to a varying degree. It regularly trumps the performance of other options. But there is a lot of leeway in the details, even with indexes.

#### Index support

***Without* pg_trgm**, there is only index support for *left anchored* search patterns. If your database cluster runs with a non-C locale (typical case), you need an index [with a special operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) for that, like `text_pattern_ops` or `varchar_pattern_ops`. Basic left-anchored regular expressions are supported by this, too. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(string text);

INSERT INTO  tbl(string)
SELECT x::text FROM generate_series(1, 10000) x;

CREATE INDEX tbl_string_text_pattern_idx ON tbl(string text_pattern_ops);

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE string ~ '^1234';  -- left anchored pattern
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=37cdd0c124d38a91de2795ef5e371151)*

***With* pg_trgm** installed, GIN or GiST indexes are possible with the operator classes `gist_trgm_ops` or `gin_trgm_ops`. These indexes support *any* `LIKE` expression, not just left anchored. And, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.7)

> Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.3, these index types also support index searches for regular-expression matches.

Details:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

---

**`SIMILAR TO`** is a very odd construct. PostgreSQL only implements it because it was defined in early versions of the SQL standard. Internally, every `SIMILAR TO` expression is rewritten with a regular expression. Therefore, for any given `SIMILAR TO` expression, there is at least one regular expression doing the same job *faster*. I ***never*** use `SIMILAR TO`.

Further reading:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: I read recently that `SIMILAR TO` might be eliminated from the next version of the ANSI SQL standard (in favor of REGEXP_LIKE) anyway. And I'm not sure that the gains in portability from using `SIMILAR TO` over `~` are worth it since other DBMSs (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL) don't support the standard.

Comment: @DavidFaber: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 49):

There is nothing wrong with `LIKE` and, IMO, no reason to favour `~` over it. Rather the opposite. [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is SQL-standard. So is [`SIMILAR TO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP), but it isn't widely supported. PostgreSQL's [`~ operator`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) (or *posix regular expression matching operator*) isn't SQL standard.

For that reason, I prefer to use `LIKE` where it's expressive enough and I only use `~` when I need the power of full regular expressions. If I ever need to port databases it's one less thing that'll hurt. I've tended to use `SIMILAR TO` when `LIKE` isn't powerful enough, but after Erwin's comments I think I'll stop doing that and use `~` when `LIKE` doesn't do the job.

Also, PostgreSQL can use a b-tree index for prefix searches (eg `LIKE 'TEST%'`) with `LIKE` or `SIMILAR TO` if the database is in the `C` locale or the index has `text_pattern_ops`. Contrary to what I wrote earlier, Pg can also use such an index for a left-anchored posix regex, it just needs an explicit '^TEST.*' so the regex can only match from the beginning. My post earlier incorrectly stated that `~` couldn't use an index for a prefix search. With that difference eliminated it's really down to whether you want to stick to standard compliant features where possible or not.

See [this demo SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4bad6/9); note the different execution plans. Note the difference between `~ '1234.*'` and `~ '^1234.*'`.

Given sample data:

```
create table test (
   blah text
);
insert into test (blah)  select x::text from generate_series(1,10000) x;
create index test_blah_txtpat_idx ON test(blah text_pattern_ops);
```

note that `~` uses a seqscan even when it's substantially more expensive (artifically so due to `enable_seqscan`) because it has no alternative, while `LIKE` uses the index. However, a corrected `~` with a left anchor uses the index too:

```
regress=# SET enable_seqscan = 'f';
SET
regress=# explain select 1 from test where blah ~ '12.*';
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000118.69 rows=2122 width=0)
   Filter: (blah ~ '12.*'::text)
(2 rows)
regress=# explain select 1 from test where blah like '12%';
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=4.55..46.76 rows=29 width=0)
   Filter: (blah ~~ '12%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_blah_txtpat_idx  (cost=0.00..4.54 rows=29 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((blah ~>=~ '12'::text) AND (blah ~<~ '13'::text))
(4 rows)
regress=# explain select 1 from test where blah ~ '^12.*';
                                     QUERY PLAN                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=5.28..51.53 rows=101 width=0)
   Filter: (blah ~ '^12.*'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_blah_txtpat_idx  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=100 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((blah ~>=~ '12'::text) AND (blah ~<~ '13'::text))
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Personally I disagree on `SIMILAR TO`. I wrote more on that in my answer. Also, it's worth mentioning, that the very common left-anchored search patterns are supported even for the regular expression operator `~`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ah, I forgot to anchor it left. Will correct my post.

Answer (score 13):

Like is just matching a part of the string either at the beginning or End or Middle
And tilt (~) is matching with regex

To explain this further let's create a table and insert some values

```
# create table users(id serial primary key, name character varying);
```

Now let's insert some values in the table

```
# insert into users (name) VALUES ('Alex'), ('Jon Snow'), ('Christopher'), ('Arya'),('Sandip Debnath'), ('Lakshmi'),('alex@gmail.com'),('@sandip5004'), ('lakshmi@gmail.com');
```

Now your table should look like this

```
 id |       name        
----+-------------------
  1 | Alex
  2 | Jon Snow
  3 | Christopher
  4 | Arya
  5 | Sandip Debnath
  6 | Lakshmi
  7 | alex@gmail.com
  8 | lakshmi@gmail.com
  9 | @sandip5004
```

### Case LIKE

```
# select * from users where name like 'A%';
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | Alex
  4 | Arya
(2 rows)
```

As you can see  `'A%'` will only get us the values whose name starts with capital A.

```
# select * from users where name like '%a%';
 id |       name        
----+-------------------
  4 | Arya
  5 | Sandip Debnath
  6 | Lakshmi
  7 | alex@gmail.com
  8 | lakshmi@gmail.com
```

As you can see  `'%a%'` will only get us the values whose name has `a` in between the name.

```
# select * from users where name like '%a';

 id | name 
----+------
  4 | Arya
```

As you can see  `'%a'` will only get us the values whose name ends with `a`.

### Case ~ (tilt)

```
# select * from users where name ~* 't';
 id |      name      
----+----------------
  3 | Christopher
  5 | Sandip Debnath
```

As you can see  `name ~* 't'` will only get us the values whose name has `t`.
`~` means case sensitive and  ~* means case insensitive
so

```
# select * from users where name ~ 'T';
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)
```

the above query gave us 0 rows as `T` was not matching with any entries

Now let's consider a case where we only need to fetch the email ids and we don't know what the mail ids have, but we know the pattern of email i.e there will be some letter or number or _ or . or - and then @ and then some more letter or number or - then . then `com` or `in` or `org` `etc` and we can create the pattern using regular expression.

now let's try to fetch results using regular expression

```
# select * from users where name ~* '[a-z0-9\.\-\_]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,5}';
 id |       name        
----+-------------------
  7 | alex@gmail.com
  8 | lakshmi@gmail.com
```

Similarly we can fetch some names which has a space in between

```
#select * from users where name ~* '[a-z]+\s[a-z]+';
 id |      name      
----+----------------
  2 | Jon Snow
  5 | Sandip Debnath
```

[a-z]+ means there can be any letter from a to z and + means it might occur 1 or more times and \s means after that there will be a space in between and then again a set of letters which can occur 1 or more times.

Hope this detailed analysis helps.

Answer (score 7):

[The `~~` operator is equivalent to `LIKE`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) `~`, on the other hand, [will match using a POSIX regular expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

Comment: Just an opinion (and thus a comment), but I dislike the ``~~`` operator, because it's Postgres-specific and loses SQL portability for no real gain.

Comment: @syrion: Sorry for being unclear, I completely agree—I'm just saying that `~` doesn't do the same thing as `LIKE` does.

Comment: @syrion And it's not as easier to search for than `LIKE`, e.g. I had to type `tilde tilde` on Google to get here

Answer (score 6):

I just did a quick and simple benchmark to look at the performance difference between the two operators *when no indexes are involved*:

```
postgres=# \timing
Timing is on.
postgres=# SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT val from generate_series(1, 10000000) x(val) WHERE val::text LIKE '%5%') AS x;
  count
─────────
 5217031
(1 row)

Time: 5631.662 ms
postgres=# SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT val from generate_series(1, 10000000) x(val) WHERE val::text ~ '5') AS x;
  count
─────────
 5217031
(1 row)

Time: 10612.406 ms
```

In this example the `LIKE` operator is almost twice as fast as the `~` operator. So if speed is of the essence I would lean towards `LIKE`, though be careful not to optimize prematurely. `~` gives you a lot more flexibility.

For those of you who are interested, here are `EXPLAIN` plans for the above queries:

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT val from generate_series(1, 10000000) x(val) WHERE val::text LIKE '%5%') AS x;
                                                              QUERY PLAN
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 Aggregate  (cost=20.00..20.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=9967.748..9967.749 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series x  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=1732.084..7404.755 rows=5217031 loops=1)
         Filter: ((val)::text ~~ '%5%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4782969
 Total runtime: 9997.587 ms
(5 rows)

postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT val from generate_series(1, 10000000) x(val) WHERE val::text ~ '5') AS x;
                                                              QUERY PLAN
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 Aggregate  (cost=20.00..20.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=15118.061..15118.061 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series x  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=1724.591..12516.996 rows=5217031 loops=1)
         Filter: ((val)::text ~ '5'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4782969
 Total runtime: 15147.950 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a huge difference. Great example!

Comment: can you provide the explain plan to see if the explanation for the delta is consistent with the explanation Craig Ringer is showing above?

Comment: Great suggestion, @eharik. Done.

Comment: So with an index-less test data set like what you're presented here your actually just confirming what Erwin is saying.  Namely that ~~ is just a faster operator than ~.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it stands for POSIX regex. Another alternative is to use the SQL standard approach to regular expressions with the  "SIMILAR TO"  operator,though it provides a more limited set of features,might be easier to understand.
I think this is a good reference from dba exchange:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql