# Am I using regular expressions incorectly on the database?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

This works:
`SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE junk='foo bar';`
This hangs for ever:
`SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE junk~'foo bar';`
This hangs for ever:
`SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE junk~'foo b.*';`
What is wrong?

EDIT: is there ever a situation where the sql query is submitted but no reply is *ever* given? For example infinite loops, bad syntax etc.

Comment: Bad syntax will produce an immediate reply with an error. It's certainly possible to have queries that never return, though, like incorrectly written recursive CTEs (`WITH RECURSIVE` queries). Most bad queries will eventually fail when the system runs out of resources, but it's possible to write ones that'll run forever. A query blocked on a lock that's held by an idle transaction will hang indefinitely (or until the idle transaction terminates), too. BTW, did you examine `explain` output for each statement as I advised so you could see what was going on? Worth doing.

Comment: If you are looking for left-anchored search terms, be sure to express it. Will be *much* faster: `junk ~ '^foo bar'`, and can be supported with an index. Generally, use `LIKE` if you can. Faster, yet. More under this [related question on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10694/3684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

Neither of your 2 queries that use regular expressions can be optimized using indexes.

So you have full scan as a result, thus it takes some time.

Answer (score 2):

All three are correct, but if you examine the query plans using [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) you'll see that the plans are very different.

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5357f/3) - note the differing execution times. Examine the query plans with "view execution plan".

In your case, the `=` is probably using a b-tree index lookup for a single value, which should be very fast, while the `~` versions are probably doing sequential scans - and quite CPU-expensive ones at that, because it has to try the regex against every single row.

Handily I just wrote about this in answer to another post. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452518/398670) which explains that `LIKE` and `SIMILAR TO` can use a suitably-created index for a prefix match like you're doing, but `~` cannot.

Try creating an index like `CREATE INDEX atable_junk_txt_idx ON aTable(junk text_pattern_ops)` then using `LIKE 'foo b%'`.

Note that every extra index will slow down every insert, update and delete, so don't create indexes you don't have to.

See [Using explain](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN) on the Pg wiki.