# Query performance in PostgreSQL using 'similar to'

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

I need to retrieve certain rows from a table depending on certain values in a specific column, named **columnX** in the example:

```
select *
from tableName 
where columnX similar to ('%A%|%B%|%C%|%1%|%2%|%3%')
```

So if **columnX** contains at least one of the values specified (A, B, C, 1, 2, 3), I will keep the row.

I can't find a better approach than using **similar to**.  The problem is that the query takes too long for a table with more than a million rows.

I've tried indexing it:

```
create index tableName_columnX_idx on tableName (columnX) 
where columnX similar to ('%A%|%B%|%C%|%1%|%2%|%3%')
```

However, if the condition is variable (the values could be other than A, B, C, 1, 2, 3), I would need a different index for each condition.

Is there any better solution for this problem?

EDIT: Thanks everybody for the feedback.  Looks like I've achieved to this point maybe because of a design mistake (topic I've posted in a [separated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194906/data-structure-design-for-database-replication-support)).

Comment: are you always going to search over single-character values? Is a query like `'%ABC%|%BCD%'` possible?

Comment: Yes, is a single-character based search.

Comment: @FedericoCristina effectively, `columnX` is a *set* represented by single-character codes in a `text` field. Correct? This implies that the order of values in `columnX` does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi), a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin.html) is fastest and simplest - unless write performance or disk space are issues, because it occupies a lot of space and adds cost for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

My additional answer is triggered by your statement:

> I can't find a better approach than using `similar to`.

If that is what you found, then your search isn't over, yet. `SIMILAR TO` is *a complete waste of time*. Literally. Postgres only includes it to comply to the (weird) SQL standard. Inspect the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for your query and you will find that `SIMILAR TO` has been replaced by a regular expression.

Internally every `SIMILAR TO` expression is rewritten to a regular expression. Consequently, for each and every `SIMILAR TO` expression there is at least one regular expression match that is a bit faster. Let `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` translate it for you, if you are not sure. You won't find this in the manual, PostgreSQL does not promise to do it this way, but I have yet to see an exception.

Further reading:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

Comment: Thanks for the link! You're right about using SIMILAR TO. Maybe I should redesing the solution in order to avoid this scenario. I've edited my question with a reference to a new domain-specific question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only going to search lists of one-character values, then split each string into an array of characters and index the array:

```
CREATE INDEX
        ix_tablename_columnxlist
ON      tableName
USING   GIN((REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(columnX, '')))
```

then search against the index:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(columnX, '') && ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: A GIN index can be quite expensive to maintain, so it isn't particularly suitable for tables with high rates of inserts/updats/deletes. This may or may not be a problem for this particular application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately these tables are constantly changing (inserts & updated)

Comment: @FedericoCristina: not aware of your scenario's details, however, in most cases frequent full scans imply more load on the server than index updates (even `GIN`). Have you actually tried both solutions? Also if you consider a redesign and are able to install extensions, you could store your flags in a native `INTARRAY` and index it with much more update-friendly `GIST`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post this as an answer because it may guide other people in the future: Why not have 6 columns, `haveA`, `haveB` ~ `have3` and do a 6-part `OR` query? Or use a bitmask?

If there are too many attributes to assign a column each, I might try creating an "attribute" table:

```
(fkey, attr) VALUES (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, '3')
```

and let the DBMS worry about the optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Maybe I should have explained better, those values (A, B, C, 1, 2, 3) where just for the example.  The complete set of options is about 24 different ones.

Comment: I'm not sure the last bit is right. If `columnX` has value `ZAB` and you're searching for `A|B` that won't match, but should.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry. Attribute it to ~40 hours of sleeplessness please :)

Answer (score 2):

This strikes me as a data modelling issue. You appear to be using a `text` field as a set, storing single character codes to identify values present in the set.

If so, I'd want to remodel this table to use one of the following approaches:

- Standard relational normalization. Drop `columnX`, and replace it with a new table with a foreign key reference to `tableName(id)` and a `charcode` column that contains one character from the old `columnX` per row, like `CREATE TABLE tablename_columnx_set(tablename_id integer not null references tablename(id), charcode "char", primary key (tablename_id, charcode))`. You can then fairly efficiently search for keys in `columnX` using normal SQL subqueries, joins, etc. If your application can't cope with that change you could always keep `columnX` and maintain the side table using triggers.
- Convert `columnX` to a `hstore` of keys with a dummy value. You can then use hstore operators like `columnX ?| ARRAY['A','B','C']`. A `GiST` index on the hstore of `columnX` should provide fairly solid performance for those operations.
- Split to an array [as recommended by Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183949/398670) if your table change rate is low and you can pay the costs of the GIN index;
- Convert `columnX` to an array of integers, use `intarray` and the intarray GiST index. Have a mapping table of codes to integers or convert in the application.

Time permitting I'll follow up with demos of each. Making up the dummy data is a pain, so it'll depend on what else is going on.

Comment: Looks like you're right about the modelling issue.  I should do some refactor there.  I've edited my question with a reference to a new domain-specific question.