# How to order query by number first and then by string in the same field

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have a db in PostgreSQL 9.0, which has a table with a string field to store client codes.
These codes are alphanumeric and can start with a letter or number, for example `1, 2, A0001-4, A0001-2, 10`

I want to order numeric first and then order by string, like

```
1, 2, 10, A0001-2, A0001-4
```

I do this with `to_number(fields, '99999999')`, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER BY to_number(legajo, '99999999'), legajo
```

But when the code is like `'ve'`, with no number, the query fails.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH empleados(legajo) AS (
   VALUES
     ('A0001-4'::text)
    ,('123.345-56')
    ,('ve')
    ,('123')
    ,('123 ve')
   ) 
SELECT *
FROM   empleados
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN legajo ~ '\D' THEN 1000000000::int
                                  ELSE to_number(legajo, '999999999')::int END
      ,legajo;
```

[`~` is the regular expression operaor.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE)
[`\D` is the classs shorthand for non-digits.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE)

Rows with non-digit characters in legajo (`legajo ~ '\D'`) come later.

[-> SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1210)

[*Never* use `SIMILAR TO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689), it's an utterly pointless operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement to find the numbers:

```
select *
from empleados
order by (case when legajo not similar to '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (case when legajo not similar to '%[^0-9]%' then to_number(legajo, '999999999') end),
         legjo;
```

The `similar to` expression is saying that all characters are digits.

EDIT:

Fixed the syntax error.  You can test this:

```
with empleados as (
      select 'abc' as legajo union all
      select '123'
     ) 
select *
from empleados
order by (case when legajo not similar to '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (case when legajo not similar to '%[^0-9]%' then to_number(legajo, '999999999') end),
         legajo;
```

The SQLFiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1144).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
from empleados
order by
    case
        when legajo similar to '%[0-9]%' then to_number(legajo, '999999999')
        else 999999999
    end,
    legajo
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c927e/2)