# Postgresql SELECT if string contains

Tags: postgresql

So I have a  in my Postgresql:

```
TAG_TABLE
==========================
id            tag_name       
--------------------------
1             aaa
2             bbb
3             ccc
```

To simplify my problem,
What I want to do is SELECT 'id' from TAG_TABLE when a string "aaaaaaaa" contains the 'tag_name'.
So ideally, it should only return "1", which is the ID for tag name 'aaa'

This is what I am doing so far:

```
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE 'aaaaaaaaaaa' LIKE '%tag_name%'
```

But obviously, this does not work, since the postgres thinks that '%tag_name%' means a pattern containing the substring 'tag_name' instead of the actual data value under that column.

How do I pass the tag_name to the pattern??

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You should use `tag_name` outside of quotes; then it's interpreted as a field of the record. Concatenate using `'||'` with the literal percent signs:

```sql
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE 'aaaaaaaa' LIKE '%' || tag_name || '%';
```

And remember that `LIKE` is case-sensitive.  If you need a case-insensitive comparison, you could do this:

```sql
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE 'aaaaaaaa' LIKE '%' || LOWER(tag_name) || '%';
```

Comment: what hapoens when tag_name is `"; drop table TAG_TABLE; --"`?

Comment: @Denis: Nothing happens. You get no row, because the `WHERE` clause evaluates to `FALSE`. The statement is not dynamic, only values are concatenated, no chance for SQL injection.

Comment: shouldn't be the order of aaaa and tag_name reversed? i mean that you should put a column name after where

Comment: @user151496 No because the pattern has to go on the right side of the `LIKE` keyword.

Comment: Beware that using variables in a `LIKE` pattern may have unintended consequences when those variables contain underscores (_) or percent characters (%). It may be necessary to escape these characters, for example with this function: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quote_for_like(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS $$ SELECT regexp_replace($1, '([\%_])', '\\\1', 'g'); $$;` (from user MatheusOl from the #postgresql IRC channel on Freenode).

Comment: This didn't work but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379009/14967240) did.

Comment: Use `ILIKE` for case insensitive search.

Answer (score 110):

A proper way to search for a substring is to use `position` function instead of `like` expression, which requires escaping `%`, `_` and an escape character (`\` by default):

```
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE position(tag_name in 'aaaaaaaaaaa')>0;
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this. No one should use the hacky regex approaches.

Comment: `LIKE` and `ILIKE` can use `gin` indices. `position` cannot.

Comment: @Grigory There must’ve been a typo in your `position`.

Comment: is it case-sensitive or case-insensitive by default?

Comment: One thing non-intuitive thing is that for postgres, position is 1 based, not 0 based. For example select position('a' in 'abc') returns 1. And if there is no match it returns 0.

Answer (score 84):

I personally prefer the simpler syntax of the `~` operator.

```sql
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE 'aaaaaaaa' ~ tag_name;
```

Worth reading through [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres) to understand the difference.
`

Comment: This works only when `tag_name` is a proper REGEX. Pretty risky.

Comment: @JakubFedyczak to match literal tag_name you can use `***=` which is mentioned in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html. However I have found that to be too much slower compared to the `strpos`/`position` solutions.

Comment: Regexes need to be compiled before they can be matched, so matching against a column name like this means it has to compile a new regex for each row considered, which will be very slow.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the solution with `'aaaaaaaa' LIKE '%' || tag_name || '%'` there
are `position` (reversed order of args) and `strpos`.

```
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE strpos('aaaaaaaa', tag_name) > 0
```

Besides what is more efficient (LIKE looks less efficient, but an index might change things), there is a very minor issue with LIKE: tag_name of course should not contain `%` and especially `_` (single char wildcard), to give no false positives.

Comment: I had to replace strpos with position, as strpos always returned 0 for me

Answer (score 1):

Try This Simple one

Column Name like '%Vesta%'

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT id FROM TAG_TABLE WHERE 'aaaaaaaa' LIKE '%' || "tag_name" || '%';
```

`tag_name` should be in quotation otherwise it will give error as tag_name doest not exist

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23321017/4826457). You are concatenating as string while it needs to be a column...

Comment: double quotes still reference a column, so this would just be identical

Comment: ⸻in cases where your column name has spaces.