# Postgres - WHERE clause on whether values contain a certain string

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

If I want to retrieve all entries such that the column `foo` value contains a string `'bar'`, is there a simple way to do this in SQL, or Postgresql?

Something like `' WHERE foo = "bar"'` but instead of `=` it would be something like `' WHERE foo CONTAINS "bar"'`.

Postgres Version 9.3

Comment: `where foo like `%bar%`'

Comment: alternatively: `where strpos(foo, 'bar')`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the SQL `LIKE` statement. With that, you use a `%` as a wildcard. So, your `WHERE` statement could be something like:

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%'
```

Answer (score 22):

One of:

1. `WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%'`
2. `WHERE foo ILIKE '%bar%' --case insensitive`
3. `WHERE foo ~* 'bar' --regex`
4. `WHERE foo ~* '\ybar\y' --matches bar but not foobar (\y is word boundary)`
5. `WHERE foo::tsvector @@ 'bar'::tsquery --matches bar but not foobar`

You can index `foo` to make `LIKE`, `ILIKE`, and `regexp` searches faster: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgtrgm.html#AEN154464
Or use a GIN or GIST index on a full-text column