# Perl DBI: Escaping a LIKE prepared statement

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I have a query that is binding a parameter to a LIKE statement as follows:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz LIKE ?');
$sth->execute("%$like%");
```

However, `$like` is a value that is entered by the user. So if the value contains any special characters recognised by the `LIKE` clause (`%`, `_`, `\`), these are passed unescaped to the database and parsed as wildcard or escape characters. For example if the user inputs `%value`, the query that will be submitted is: `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz LIKE '%%value'`, rather than `LIKE '%\%value`, which is what I would expect.

Currently I am using regular expressions to escape the field manually:

```perl
# Escape LIKE wildcard characters
$like =~ s!\\!\\\\!g;
$like =~ s!%!\\%!g;
$like =~ s!_!\\_!g;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz LIKE ?');
$sth->execute("%$like%");
```

but it feels like the escaping is something DBI should be able to handle. I played around with `DBI::quote`, but this is designed for quoting entire fields, so in this case it would also quote the `%` symbols I am adding, and the documentation for `DBI::quote` specifically states:

> The quote() method should not be used with "Placeholders and Bind
> Values".

Is there a better way to bind a user-supplied input to a LIKE clause while escaping the input and adding relevant wildcard characters, without resorting to manually escaping the input?

Comment: `$like =~ s/(?=[\\%_])/\\/g`

Comment: @Borodin I wasn't aware of Look-Around Assertions! Equivalent to `s/([\\%_])/\\$1/g` it seems. However my goal is to remove the need for the regex, not to rewrite it.

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as a solution. There's nothing in `DBI` that will do what you describe

Comment: I think the best approach is to monkeypatch that functionality into DBI as something like `quote_like()` and then use that.

Comment: @simbaque yes, I think that's the sort of approach I'm going to take. A little surprised this is not supported out of the box. I'm wondering if there are driver-specific issues that make this difficult to do. Reading up on LIKE a bit more, it looks like I should be escaping `[` and `]` too.

Comment: While not what the OP is asking for, rewriting the query to be [`... WHERE POSITION( ? IN baz ) > 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298666/132382) is an easier approach than worrying about each underlying database's LIKE/ESCAPE behavior (which varies, and may vary with "sql mode," etc.).

Answer (score -3):

Despite what the documentation for `DBI::quote` says, `LIKE` parameters are a bit of a special case. What you want to do is almost what you already have in your example: first make sure there are no user-provided metacharacters by applying `quote` to the user-provided string (you do this with regexps in your example), then add your own metacharacters (the percent signs, in this case), then use it as food for the bind parameter.

Comment: `DBI::quote` does not escape the wildcards used by the `LIKE` clause. It also returns a quoted string. Thus an input of `user_input` comes out of `quote()` as `'user_input'`, with the `_` unescaped (`%` characters are also unescaped) and the whole input quoted, meaning it's still necessary to use regular expressions or some other method to do the escaping and add in the metacharacters inside the quotes.

Comment: Forgot to mention: passing a quoted string into a prepared statement with also result in the string being double quoted.