# Remove " " from values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pattern-matching

In PostgreSQL a column contains values such as:

```
"Sample1"
"Sample2"
```

Is there an efficient way to go through each record removing the `" "` marks?

This seems like a relatively straightforward operation, but I am baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ColName = REPLACE(ColName, '"', '');
WHERE ColName SIMILAR TO '%"%'
```

You can use `LIKE` operator as well instead of `SIMILAR TO`.

Comment: Fantastic, banging my head on the desk! @Raging_Bull

Comment: Another option is `trim(colname, '"')`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an `efficient way`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col = translate(col, '"', '')
WHERE  col LIKE '%"%';
```

- [*Never* use `SIMILAR TO`, its an utterly pointless operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689), only included in Postgres for standard compliance. There is hope the standard will include a regular expression match (like [`~`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in Postgres) instead in the future.
- For replacing single characters, [`translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) is simpler and faster than [`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html).
- If you only want to replace leading and / or trailing characters, use [`trim()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) / [`ltrim()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) / [`rtrim()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) instead. And also change to `WHERE col LIKE '"%' OR col LIKE '%"'` respectively.