# Using LIKE pattern dynamically in execute format query in postgresql--9.5

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I want to insert footext into LIKE pattern dynamically, but it gives error saying

> ERROR: unrecognized conversion type specifier "'"........

This is my query:

```
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format ('SELECT foocolumn
             FROM footable  
                WHERE foocolumnother LIKE ''%L%''  ', footext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a `%` into the format string you need to double it e.g. `%F%%`

`%L`also correctly adds single quotes so you don't need to put them in the format string.

However: using `%F%%` would generate `'bla'%` - which is incorrect.

You need to add the wildcard to the *variable* not the format string:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format ('SELECT foocolumn
         FROM footable  
         HERE foocolumnother LIKE %L'  ', concat(footext, '%'));
```

Comment: PG 11 in 2020., this results with the same error "unrecognized conversion type specifier " ' ". The answer by slevin solves it.

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party, but according to Erwin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689) and the [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html), you can also try the `~` character of regex. So test out this

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format ('SELECT foocolumn
             FROM footable  
                WHERE foocolumnother ~ %L  ', footext);
```

Comment: nice one, saved my searches! Thanks mate! ))

Comment: This is gold, and if you want case insensitive searches use ~*

Answer (score 0):

Another late entry. Doubling both the single-quotes and percents works for me in Postgres 11.x:

```
l_query text := FORMAT('
    SELECT e.gid, e.sessionname, e.shared, e.created, e.created_by 
    FROM exercise e
    WHERE LOWER(e.created_by) LIKE ''%%%s%%'';'
    , LOWER(p_user));

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE l_query;
```