# PostgreSQL CHECK Constraint to Limit Specific Characters

Tags: postgresql, constraints, special-characters, check-constraints

I need to limit five special characters in my column specifically: period, comma, single-quotes, double-quotes, and  dollar sign.

I understand I can use the following to only allow alphanumeric characters but I need to be able to accept the other special characters as well.

```
-- Check Constraint to only Allow Numbers & Alphabets 
ALTER TABLE Table_Name  
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_No_Special_Characters 
CHECK (Column_Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
```

Comment: `CHECK (Column_Name !~ '[.,''"]')`

Comment: @Abelisto Please post as an answer, with simple explanation like "use the negated chararacter class in a regexp"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.  I have a table with a column that contains [Enzyme Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_Commission_number) numbers, typically in the form `1.1.1.1` -- i.e. four period-delimited integers where the integers can be 1-3 digits (e.g., `4.2.3.181` ...).

I can ensure that pattern through the following CHECK constraint:

```
...
ec_num TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (ec_num ~ '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')
...
```

where

- the tilde (`~`) is a regular expression match ("similarity comparison") operator, described in ref. [1] and [2] (below)
- `[0-9]` matches any single digit, modified by `{n}` which specifies the degree of repetition of the preceding expression -- see ref. [3]
- the period is `\`-escaped, otherwise it would match any single character -- again, see ref [3]

If I try to insert a malformed number, e.g. `1.1.1,4` (note the comma preceding the 4) then PostgreSQL throws an error, similar to:

```
ERROR:  23514: new row for relation "kegg_enzymes" violates
        check constraint "kegg_enzymes_ec_num_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains
         (4, 1.1.1,4, (r,r)-butanediol dehydrogenase, (R,R)-butanediol dehydrogenase).
```

[1] [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres)

[2] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

[3] https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: ~ will match any part of the string, meaning "foo1.2.3.4bar" is also valid. You should use the ^ and $ characters to indicate that the match must be at the start and the end (the entire string), not just a part of it. Like so:

'^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'