# Instead of LIKE and ~, why only SIMILAR TO works when doing regex match with alternatives

Tags: regex, postgresql

With the example below, I only got TRUE with the expression SIMILAR TO; LIKE and ~ both showed FALSE (failed to work here I guess?)

As SIMILAR TO is not favorable in many SO posts, I'd like to learn if there's a way doing regex match with alternatives by using LIKE or ~.

```
SELECT 'thomas' SIMILAR TO '%(h|x)%'
-- result: t

SELECT 'thomas' LIKE '%(h|x)%'
-- result: f

SELECT 'thomas' ~* '%(h|x)%'
-- result: f
```

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions. Where in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-like) did you get that impression?

Comment: *Never* use `SIMILAR TO`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459689/939860

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-like) supports pattern matching using `_` for any single character and `%` for any sequence of characters so this:

```
SELECT 'thomas' LIKE '%(h|x)%'
```

doesn't work because LIKE doesn't understand `(...)` for grouping or `|` for alternation, those are just literal characters in a LIKE pattern.

[SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-similarto-regexp) supports `_` and `%` the same as LIKE but adds grouping with `(...)`, alternation with `|`, and a few other things so this:

```
SELECT 'thomas' SIMILAR TO '%(h|x)%'
```

works as expected.

[`~*`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-posix-regexp) uses POSIX regexes so `(...)` is for grouping and `|` is for alternation but `%` is just a percent sign; that means that this:

```
SELECT 'thomas' ~* '%(h|x)%'
```

is looking for an `h` or `x` surrounded by percent signs and doesn't work they way you expect it to.

Your `~*` version will work if you use a proper regex like:

```
SELECT 'thomas' ~* '(h|x)' -- alternation
SELECT 'thomas' ~* 'h|x'   -- alternation without an unnecessary grouping
SELECT 'thomas' ~* '[hx]'  -- or a character class
```

The documentation linked to above covers all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ~* in this case:

```
SELECT 'thomas' ~* '.*(h|x).*'
```

or

```
SELECT 'thomas' ~* 'h|x'
```

Keep in mind that you should use [**POSIX**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) regex syntax with ~, ~* operators.