# Postgres regex begins with ^ and ends with $ using LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Newbie question.  I'm looking for stings beginning with letter 'R'
this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE  'R%'
```

this does not

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '^R%'
```

WHY?
Also just curious, if I want it to end with `R`, I use the `$?`

```
'%R$'
```

Pattern matching is not explained well here. If you know any other resources for a layman please share.  thanks
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Do you mean the pg docs on pattern matching aren't sufficient? What isn't "explained well" for you?

Comment: That documentation clearly shows that `LIKE` has its own syntax, which is different from regex, which is applied using `SIMILAR TO`. Nowhere does it indicate that you can mix or match arbitrarily and expect it to know which kind of pattern-matching you want at any given time.

Comment: Wildcards are not regexes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46836355/330315

Answer (score 25):

The manual is very clear `LIKE` and regular expressions are two different things.

**LIKE**

Accordingly to the manual:

> The LIKE expression returns **true** if the string matches the supplied pattern. (As expected, the NOT LIKE expression returns **false** if LIKE returns true, and vice versa. An equivalent expression is NOT (string LIKE pattern).)

So, LIKE returns true or false while matching a string.

`%` is similar to `*` in filesearch, it means it will match zero or any after or before.

- `R%` R and any character after.
- `%R` Any character befor and R

`LIKE` it's used instead of `=`, and more functionalities are explained in the manual.

```
-- Gets zero or any characters before one R
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%R'

-- Gets zero or any characters after one R
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'R%'
```

**ILIKE**

`LIKE` is case sensitive, to make it case insensitive you can use `ILIKE`

**REGULAR EXPRESION**

In postgreSQL, for a regular expression match, instead of using `=` you use `~` and the regular expression format is accordingly to the [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) standards

An example is:

```
-- Gets zero or any spaces numbers and text characters before one R
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ~ '^[\s\w]*[R]{1}$'

-- Gets zero or any spaces numbers and text characters after one R
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ~ '^[R]{1}[\s\w]*$'
```

In the manual there's the explanation for all the available operators for regular expressions. How to use regular expressions is other thing and it is in the [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) standards; that has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: very helpful explanation, thank you.  looks like I was trying to use the two interchangeably.