# PostgreSQL similar to operator behaviour

Tags: postgresql

I find PostgreSQL similar to operator works little strange. I accidentally checked for space in below query but surprised with the result.

`select 'Device Reprocessing' similar to '%( )%' --return true
select 'Device Reprocessing' similar to '%()%' --return true
select 'DeviceReprocessing' similar to '%()%' --return true`

Why 2nd and the 3rd query returns true? Is empty pattern always return true?

What I understand about SIMILAR TO operator is returns true or false depending on whether its pattern matches the given string.

Comment: There is no point in using `SIMILAR TO`. Ever. I use `LIKE` or regular expressions instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a group with nothing in it, meaning anything will match.  I think you will find any string matches `%()%`, even an empty string.

Normally you would use this grouping to list options so:

```
select 'DeviceReprocessing' similar to '%(Davinci|Dog)%'
```

Would return false since it contains neither "Davinci" nor "Dog", but this:

```
select 'DeviceReprocessing' similar to '%(vice|Dog)%'
```

would return true since it does contain at least one of the options.

Your first condition is true because the expression does contain a space.

I actually prefer the Regular Expression notation that does not require the `%` wildcards:

```
select 'DeviceReprocessing' ~ 'vice|Dog'
```