# No operator matches the given name and argument type(s): What needs to be cast?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, case

I'm getting an error, and I cannot figure out why. I know the error is telling me to cast a type but I'm not sure on what?

What part of `CASE` is the operator?

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = boolean
> LINE 6:              WHEN lower(foo.name) SIMILAR TO '%(foo
>                     ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

My query:

```
SELECT foo.name,
       bar.city,
       MAX(foo.total - bar.tax_amount),
       CASE bar.name
            WHEN lower(foo.name) SIMILAR TO '%(foo|bar|baz)%' THEN true
            ELSE false
        END
        ....
GROUP BY foo.name, bar.city;
```

Comment: `CASE bar.name` should just be `CASE` (remove the `bar.name`)

Comment: Ah yes, the documentation makes sense now. When I don't have an `expression` in the case, it just returns a boolean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply want:

```
SELECT foo.name,
       bar.city,
       MAX(foo.total - bar.tax_amount),
       (CASE WHEN lower(foo.name) SIMILAR TO '%(foo|bar|baz)%' THEN true
            ELSE false
        END)
        ....
GROUP BY foo.name, bar.city;
```

The `CASE` expression has two forms.  One searches for values for a given expression.  This takes a column or expression right after the `CASE`.  The second searches through various expressions, stopping at the first one.  This takes the `WHEN` clause right after the `CASE`.

Or even more simply:

```
SELECT foo.name, bar.city,
       MAX(foo.total - bar.tax_amount),
       (lower(foo.name) SIMILAR TO '%(foo|bar|baz)%') 
        ....
GROUP BY foo.name, bar.city;
```

The `CASE` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your [`CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) had a syntax error, [like @a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235319/no-operator-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types-what-needs-to-be-cast/48235427#comment83453279_48235319).

But you don't even need `CASE` at all in this particular case for a `boolean` result. Just:

```
foo.name ~* '(foo|bar|baz)'
```

That's all.

[**`~*`** being the case-insensitive regular expression match operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)

*Never* use `SIMILAR TO`:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

Comment: In case you wonder: the word "case" is used with three different meanings here.