# postgres - using SIMILAR TO in a CASE clause

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a column which contains the string of a scanned barcode. I want to find a specific match and return in a new column the string 'match' and 'noMatch'

The regex for the barcode is

> '[0-9]{5,8}\%[0-9]*\%'

e.g. 13412432%10000%

My query is

```
SELECT 
report."barcode" SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{5,8}\%[0-9]*\%',
(CASE report."barcode" WHEN (report."barcode" SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{5,8}\%[0-9]*\%') THEN 'match'
ELSE 'noMatch'
END) AS matchColumn
FROM report
```

However I'm always getting this error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
>   LINE 3: (CASE report."barcode" WHEN (report."barcode...
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Character: 106

I'm fairly new to SQL so when the docs says that it expects a true/false statement after WHEN I figured I could use the SIMIAR TO pattern matching since it returns boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have it on good authority (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459689/1278553) that there is no good reason to use "similar to."  From the referenced link:

> SIMILAR TO is part of the SQL standard, but it is very odd syntax, and
>   the only reason PostgreSQL supports it, is to stay standard compliant.
>   Internally, every SIMILAR TO expression is rewritten with a regular
>   expression. Therefore, for any given SIMILAR TO expression, there is
>   at least one regexp doing the same job faster.

On that note, if you change this to a normal regular expression it should even be as simple as this:

```
select
  r.barcode, 
  case
    when r.barcode ~ '\d{5,8}%\d+%' then 'match'
    else 'noMatch'
  end as matchcolumn
from report r
```

You don't need to escape the `%` character with a regex.

If you aren't okay with that pattern occuring in the middle of a string, you may want to anchor the beginning and/or end of the regex:

```
'^\d{5,8}%\d+%$'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra reference to the column after the `case`.  The expression you want is:

```
SELECT report."barcode" SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{5,8}\%[0-9]*\%',
       (CASE WHEN report."barcode" SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{5,8}\%[0-9]*\%' 
             THEN 'match'
             ELSE 'noMatch'
        END) AS matchColumn
FROM report;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to omit `report."barcode"` after case

```
          Case --omit this report."barcode
              when  ......
```