# Is there a way to express AND in SIMILAR TO ignoring order of matches?

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table column that contains 1 to many hashtags (e.g. #a, #b, etc.). I want to write a query that finds rows where all tags from a given set exist (e.g. #a and #b) while not picking up other rows that have some but not all of the tags (e.g. only #a or only #b).

I can see how to do this with multiple LIKE statements (e.g. LIKE '%#a %' AND LIKE '%#b%') but I would really like to do it with a single statement. I can see how to do this with SIMILAR TO but not in a way that ignores ordering. The following would work but only if I include all possible combinations of ordering.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field SIMILAR TO '(%#a%)(%#b%)|(%#b%)(%#a%)'
```

This works but having to list all combinations of the tags I'm looking for would be a royal pain and prone to error. Is there a way to express 'AND' in SIMLAR TO (or another function) in Redshift that ignores order?

Comment: Do note: `LIKE` may yield [better performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696) than a regex call. And as RedShift uses a variant dialect of Postgres, heed the PGSQL guru @Erwin who advises: [Never user `SIMILAR TO`. It's pointless.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459689/1422451).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to capture the whole tag in any position and not match on incomplete tags:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (field LIKE '#a#%' OR field LIKE '%#a') AND
      (field LIKE '#b#%' OR field LIKE '%#b')
```

This avoids matching data such as `#ac#b`

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` and `LIKE`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE field LIKE '%#a%' AND
      field LIKE '%#b%';
```